# Setting comment for layer in the information from provider

Tags: qgis-3, layers, pyqgis-3

How to add comment in Layer Properties, as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: I can see the comment via `layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer_name")[0];layer.dataProvider().dataComment()` but have not yet found a method that sets the comment. I am also interested in the answer to this question.

Comment: We will definitely find that answer.

Comment: See the doc : https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataProvider.html#a4005f043ffa86956dc0001d06526bb29 . It says `Returns a short comment for the data that this provider is providing access to (e.g. the comment for postgres table).`, so, IMHO, not for shapefiles.

Comment: I'm actually intending to set a comment for a geopackage layer

Comment: GeoPackage (and, in fact, SQLite) doesn't seem to admit table comments like PostgreSQL does (e.g. `COMMENT ON TABLE mytable IS 'This is mytable';`). See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426205/sqlite-adding-comments-to-tables-and-columns).